# How do you get the user details like the username after successfully login in using a token in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

I use Angular 8 on my frontend and Django DRF as my backend. I'm currently able to get logged in with my authentication token as well as using angular http interceptor.

What I can't seem to comprehend is how do you get the user details of the logged in user to show for example in a dashboard header?

Since all I get back from the server is a token and no user data?

Comment: There is no such thing as "angular token". My guess is that you are using some OAuth2 / OIDC provider. And some npm package to authenticate with that provider. You will have to provide much more information about what you are doing (which front end library are you using? which grant / flow are you using? how is your provider confgiured?) if you expect anyone to be able to help you out.

Comment: @TotallyNewb Well that's rude - so yeah we'd know to which authentication provider it is are you using a custom authoriser?

Comment: Also upvoted as you're relatively new, just try and remember to include as much detail as possible!

Comment: Well @MrkFldig i have tried using 2 authentication providers the first is JWT and the other is a python package named **djoser** and both work fine and i'm quite sure the authentication might not be an issue here, my concern is mostly on how i can fetch the payload or the details of the user and render them on my component.

Comment: Sure so the JWT token is encoded using a secret key you'd need to decode the token and then you'll access to the claims, you wouldn't wanna do this client side though as the secret key would be visible to users.